# Referencing Angular form with 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-forms

I have an angular directive (1.4) I'm switching over to the component syntax (1.5).  The existing code calls the form.$setPristine() if a form reset button is clicked.  When I switch it to a component and try to call from a jasmine test, the form variable is undefined.

```
  ctrl.resetForm = function () {
    ctrl.employee = {};
    ctrl.myForm.$setPristine();
  };
```

Test file:

```
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $scope.myForm = jasmine.createSpyObj('myForm', ['$setPristine']);

  ctrl = _$componentController_(
  'myComponent', {
    $scope: $scope,
    EmployeeSvc: EmployeeSvc,
    LoggingSvc: LoggingSvc,
    SessionSvc: SessionSvc
  });
  ctrl.$onInit();
```

form.html

```
 <form name="myForm" class="form" novalidate>
```

Error:

```
debug.html:38 TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
```

Comment: What the template code? and do you tried to initialize form like `ctrl.myForm = {}`

Comment: If you may provide something in plunker will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the spy on the component controller after it has been initialized.  $scope does not need to be passed in.

```
ctrl = _$componentController_(
'sbEmployeeCreate', { 
     EmployeeSvc: EmployeeSvc,
     LoggingSvc: LoggingSvc,
     SessionSvc: SessionSvc
});
ctrl.$onInit();
ctrl.myForm = jasmine.createSpyObj('myForm', ['$setPristine']);
```

In the template, use $ctrl for the form name.

```
<form name='$ctrl.myForm'>
```